# Delay in publishing message on topic using aws-sdk iotData.publish on aws lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am using aws-sdk for publishing message on topic below is the code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
AWS.config.credentials = {
    accessKeyId: 'myaccesskeyid',
    secretAccessKey: 'mysecretaccesskey'
}

function LEDOnIntent() {
    this.iotdata = new AWS.IotData({
        endpoint: 'XXXXXXXXX.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
    });
}

LEDOnIntent.prototype.publishMessage = function() {
    console.log('>publishMessage');
    var params = {
        topic: 'test_topic',
        /* required */
        payload: new Buffer('{action : "LED on"}') || 'STRING_VALUE',
        qos: 1
    };
    this.iotdata.publish(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else {
            console.log("Message published : " + data); // successful response
        }
    });
}
```

It works fine in local unit testing but when I deploy this code on AWS lambda then I got very uneven behaviour. For the first few requests it will not publish message then it will work fine when I continuously test it. When I test after some break then again it stop working for some initial requests.

Comment: did check Lambda logs in CloudWatch at the time it was not working?

Comment: Yes. It invoked lambda but delay in publishing message. So when I hit  request I see ">publishMessage" in log but not "Message published : ..."

Comment: There is a reason for the delay when you run after a break, which I have added in the answer. It would worth to check how long will it take for initial Lambda setup. What can you do is to do initial publish, leave few seconds and try subsequent request. Just to identify how long the delay would be

Answer (score 0):

Behind the scene, Lambda runs like a container model. It means to create a container when needs and destroy it if doesn't require the container.

The reason you see a delay in the initial request because It takes time to set up a container and do the necessary bootstrapping, which adds some latency each time the Lambda function is invoked. You typically see this latency when a Lambda function is invoked for the first time or after it has been updated because AWS Lambda tries to reuse the container for subsequent invocations of the Lambda function.

AWS Lambda maintains the container for some time in anticipation of another Lambda function invocation. In effect, the service freezes the container after a Lambda function completes, and thaws the container for reuse if AWS Lambda chooses to reuse the container when the Lambda function is invoked again.

Please read the official documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-introduction.html)